# How can I make order for has_many model on Ruby on Rails4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, -> {order "number DESC"}
end
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :section   
end


#controller
@sections = Section.order("number DESC")
```

Each models have number column.
I suppose default order of items is "number DESC".
But I want reorder or add some other conditions on items.
Does someone know how to make dynamic conditions or order?

Comment: Can you elaborate what conditions you wish to add?

Comment: like this


@sections = Section.where(:category => "TEST", :display => true).order("number DESC")

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for scopes listed here in the docs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes This is a way to allow you to create different sorts and have it be class methods.

By default, it will order by id asc (buy you have changed it in your definition there)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the sort order with an option on has_many itself:

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, :order => 'number DESC'
end
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :section   
end

#controller
@sections = Section.find(:id)
@items = @sections.items
```

or you can use ActiveRecord with order:

```
@sections = Section.find(:id)
@items = @sections.items.find(:all, :order => 'number DESC')
#or
@items = @sections.items.all(:order => 'number DESC')
```